# Cropping circular image in IOS using OpenCv

Tags: ios, image, opencv, image-processing

I am developing face features detection in my project.

Heretofore i have developed detecting the face, then finding the eyes within the face. 
I want to crop the eyes which are in circular .

```
   circle( mask, center, radius, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 ); 
                  image.copyTo( dst, mask );
```

Here in the above code , I am able to Mask image with black color leaving eye region. now I am want to crop only the Eye region.

Can anybody help me out on this issue.Please check below image

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165906/how-to-crop-image-inside-the-circle-in-uiimageview-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cropping*, by definition, means cutting an axis aligned rectangle from a larger image, leaving a smaller image.

If you want to "crop" a non-axis-aligned rectangle, you will have to use a mask. The mask can be the size of the full image (this is sometimes convenient), or as small and the smallest bounding (axis-aligned) rectangle containing all the pixels you want to leave visible.

This mask can be *binary*, meaning that it indicates whether or not a pixel is visible, or it can be an *alpha-mask* which indicated the degree of transparency of any pixel within it, with `0` indicating a non-visible pixel and (for 8-bit mask image) `255` indicating full opacity.

In your example above you can get the sub-image ROI (Region-Of-Interest) like this:

```
cv::Mat eyeImg = image(cv::Rect(center.x - radius, // ROI x-offset, left coordinate
                                center.y - radius, // ROI y-offset, top coordinate 
                                2*radius,          // ROI width
                                2*radius));        // ROI height
```

Note that `eyeImg` is not a copy, but refers to the same pixels within `image`. If you want a copy, add a `.clone()` at the end.

Comment: Ok can you tell me how to crop only eye region in the above image ?

Comment: What would you like to do? Create a new smaller image containing the circle or creating a mask the size of the image?

Comment: I want to create new image , this image should be only Eye image . how to crop it .

Comment: I hope you got ? I have the rectangle of eyes , and from that i am getting center and radius and drawing the circle , then next i need only eye region as the image .

Comment: so you want a "round" image? standard computer images (like in openCV) are always rectangles sized width*height.

Comment: Yes i need the round eye image .