# How to enable scrollView.gestureRecognizers in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a  scrollView and it has an imageview. When I disable the user interaction to zoom:

```
scrollView.gestureRecognizers = false;
```

And then I want to enable the interactions, the interactions do not work.

And with

```
scrollView.gestureRecognizers = true;
```

Is impossible, because this line returns an error.

I'm trying to add the gestures function again but it does not work..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];

doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

How can add the functions again??

Thanks!

Comment: I assume reading the documentation is out of scope for some reason…

Comment: I read documentation and search this, but I have some error, because firstly the zoom does work correctly, but then use ScrollView . gestureRecognizers =  false ; i get error that not solve with documentation...

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration for the `gestureRecognizers` property:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *gestureRecognizers
```

It's an array, so it makes no sense that you would set it to `true` or `false`.

Just enumerate the array and set the `enabled` property to each gesture recognizer.

BTW: Setting the property to `false` works because `false` and `nil` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    maximumZoomScale = self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale;
    minimumZoomScale = self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;

    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

and

```
scrollView.gestureRecognizers = true;
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: scrollView.gestureRecognizers = true; line gets error: implicit conversion 'int' to NSArray is disabled with ARC

Comment: Have you set scrollView content size ? if yes then no need of that line just skip it. and using above line you can disable zooming.

Comment: zoom is correct, and ScrollView . gestureRecognizers =  false ; i need use this. But then use this only can do double tap gesture

Comment: So set that double tap gesture on image view why you try to set it on scroll view?

Comment: I'm using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165906/how-to-crop-image-inside-the-circle-in-uiimageview-in-ios  then I do zoom in a uiscrollView with uiimageView

Comment: So now what is the issue ?

Comment: you have reason "So set that double tap gesture on image view why you try to set it on scroll view? " I was setting pinch gesture to view and not to scrollView. thanks!