# Capture UIView without using renderInContext:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to create video from my screen and for that I'm going to capture the view but I don't want to use `renderInContext:` due to some reason. I'm using now `drawViewHierarchyInRect:`, but this is limited to iOS 7 and my app supports earlier iOS versions, too. Will I be fined for using `drawViewHierarchyInRect:`?

this is my code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: It calls drawInRect: method which I am using for tile images in other class. And it makes my app inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you don't want to use `renderInContext` because it is less efficient, but for iOS versions prior to 7, that's the technique you should use (because if you attempt to use `drawViewHierarchyInRect` in iOS versions prior to 7.0, the app will crash). So, here is a rendition that uses `drawViewHierarchyInRect` when it's available, but `renderInContext` when not:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
    BOOL success = [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    NSAssert(success, @"drawViewHierarchyInRect failed");
} else {
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

That way, you'll use the more efficient mechanism for iOS 7+, but it at least won't crash when running on earlier versions.

Comment: It works but unfortunately create break in **CFDataGetBytes(image, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(image)), destPixels);** which I've use to write image into video

Comment: That sounds like a very different issue. When I want to get pixel data from a `UIImage`, I get the `CGImage` for the `UIImage` and then use the technique that Apple discusses in [QA1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22897776/1271826 for an example.